# Display an Array (from ViewModel) within Kendo View template

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

At work I'm just starting out with JavaScript, MVVM, and Kendo's JS framework, all at once, and I have a fairly simple problem.

I've created a View Model that allows Superheroes to be registered.

The JSBin I'm working in: http://jsbin.com/gewu/3/edit?html,js,output

Here's the HTML(view):

```
<div id="view">

  Superhero: <input data-bind="value: name" /><br/>
  Superpower: <input data-bind="value:power"type="text">
    <label for="">from Earth?<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:fromEarth"></label>
    <button data-bind="click: registerHero" >Display User Info</button>

<div id="array-display"></div>
<p>Entries: <span data-bind="text: knownHeroes.length"></span></p>


</div>
```

And here's the JS (viewModel):

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({

  knownHeroes : [],

  name: "Hulk",
  power:"Stength",
  fromEarth: true,

  registerHero: function() {
        var name = this.get("name");
        var power = this.get("power");
        var fromEarth = this.get("fromEarth");
    this.knownHeroes.push({"name":name,"power":power,"fromEarth":fromEarth});

}


});

kendo.bind($("#view"), viewModel);
```

Now, I'm trying to get the View to loop through and display the array of `knownHeroes`. But it won't render anything. I know the data is being pushed to the array, because I can see the array.length increasing, and I can look up specific values in the array. I'm assuming the problem has to do with how I'm referencing the array in the view. But I'm not sure. Here's the template I've written:

HTML:

```
  <script id="registry-view" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <ul>
  # for (var i=0; i < knownHeroes.length; i++) { #
    <li>
      <ul>
         <li>#= knownHeroes[i].name #</li>
         <li>#= knownHeroes[i].power #</li>
         <li>#= knownHeroes[i].fromEarth #</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    # } #
 </ul>
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        var template = kendo.template($("#registry-view").html());
        $("#array-display").html(template); //Append the result
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got some mistakes.

First of all you got script wrote in html portion of this jsbin as well as in javascript section. Html part executes first so the viewModel isn't defined yet (check console for errors)

Also the object you pass to the template is stored always in "data" variable.

Last mistake is when using your desing, anytime you add any new data row, whole template needs to be reloaded (including all previously added data rows)

I corrected some of your mistakes in following jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jomemuko/1/edit (actually you need to hit the Run with JS button to make it work - some script loading issue I don't have time for)

Ideally you should use a listView widget and assign it a template for only one item. Also in your viewModel you should create a kendo dataSource and pass it as an option to newly created listView. Then in the viewModel you should refine your registerHero function to make it add the hero to the dataSource. Widget should automatically refresh.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a ton... I'll take a look when I get to work and let you know how it goes.